# Is it okay to have type checking code when working with databases?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to insert some code into a database. But, i have encountered a problem while working with models that are subclasses of each other. I have a list that holds all these subclases.

```
List<Metric> metrics = experiment.getMetrics();

for(Metric m : metrics) {
    int id = m.getId();
    // type checking code

}
```

Metric has sublcases of Rating and Quantity. Each of these in turn have there own uniquely defined tables. I am conflicted over the idea of using type checking. But I don't see any immediate solution. One alternative, which doesn't seem any better, would be to create a new column in the Metric table called metric_type. But this would lead to something quite similar to type checking. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to typecheck? How is `Rating` different from `Quantity` ?

Comment: @NikosTzianas Rating has and quantity have different tables. And Metric is their super class. My code has a list of objects with a type of Metric. I want to iterate the list and depending on whether it is a Rating or Quantity object, execute the proper code to insert the object into their respective tables. Please don't reccomend JPA. I know what it is, but I am deciding to do this vanilla.

Comment: @azro I disagree with that suggestion. All the needed info is already explained above. Rating and quantity have their own tables because they have extended Metric differently.

Comment: Perhaps `Metric` is the problem. Eliminate it and implement `experiment.getRatings()` and `experiment.getQuantities()`. Using inheritance with data often leads to this kind of problem, because polymorphism is not desirable in data the way it is in services... plus relational databases don't support it.

Comment: You can make your `Metric` class an abstract one and have abstract template methods for CRUD operations - then implement such methods in your `Rating` and `Quantity` classes.

Comment: @jaco0646 That's a excellent suggestion, probably the best one I have received. I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @FahimFarook That is what I decided to do. How would I implement CRUD inside Metric? Should I have a DBService object that I pass into Metric?

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered [Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) due to mapping between not fully compatible systems. Since inheritance is not possible between tables in the relational model you will have to sacrifice something in the object model that uses inheritance. There will be edge cases no matter what you do unless you switch to an [object database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database).

If you define a custom CRUD operations in classes that extend `Metric` loading entites can be tricky. What exactly will be loaded by `Metric.get(id)` if each table has it's own PK sequence and both `Rating` and `Quantity` can have the same numeric PK value.

You can take a look on how JPA solves this problem. It uses custom annotations e.g. `@MappedSuperclass` and `@Entity`. I guess that's a form of type checking.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning "Object-relational impedance mismatch". *"You can take a look on how JPA solves this problem."* - how *a JPA implementation* (e.g. Hibernate) solves the problem

Comment: I have definitely encountered difficulties. That is why, knowing I am not helped by JPA, I tried to keep it simple with only one level of inheritance and using the index as the primary for each. I'm sorry, but I don't see how having the same primary key is a problem. As long as I know which subclass I am working with I can use the PK on the proper table. I have decided to place a DBservice class in Metric and have the sublasses invoke the correct method to insert itself. Do you think this a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

**I wouldn't suggest you to type check**

The OOP way to solve this would be to make an `insert` method in the `Metric` class.
Then override the method both in `Rating` and `Quality` with the appropriate code that inserts the object in the respective table.

```
for(Metric m : metrics) {
    int id = m.getId();
    m.insert();

}
```

Inside your loop simply call `insert` and due to late-binding the appropriate method will be called and the right code will be executed.